# How to calculate the standard error for proportion by groups

Tags: r

Im struggling today with some basic statistics. I want to calculate the standard error of the proportion by group.

this is code I use for proportion by group:

```
tapply(dt$v1, dt$v2, function(x){prop.table(table(x))})
```

This is formula for standard error of propotion `SE = sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)` where `p=proportion` and `n=total population`.

I would like to include this formula in above code, is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your data set (e.g. using `dput(dt)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this just be:

```
tapply(dt$v1, dt$v2, function(x){prop <- prop.table(table(x))
                                 SE <- sqrt(prop*(1-prop)/length(x))})
```

If you wanted both to be returned then add a line:

```
                            list(prop=prop, SE=SE)
```